# sendmail not receiving or sending messages to outside world

Tags: sendmail, telnet

Using box1 and `telnet box1.mydomain.net 25`:
(1) I can send and receive message to self (from: user@box1.mydomain.net to user@box1.mydomain.net)
(2) I can send  and receive message with a sender email address from the outside world (from: somebody@something.com to: user@box1.mydomain.net)

but

(a) if I'm coming in from the outside world, i.e. from: somebody@something.com to: user@box1.mydomain.net, or (b) if I try to send message from box1 to the outside world messages are no delivered, delayed, and ultimately returned.

Trying to debug the situation I use a box2 in the outside world to contact box1. It finds the public IP of box1 but cannot connect:

```
box2-$: telnet box1.mydomain.net
Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

If I do the same thing when box2 is on the same 192.168.0.0 network as box1 then I can connect to box1 and `telnet box1.mydomain.net 25` succeeds.

QUESTION: Is there something wrong with my sendmail configuration? Is something wrong with my name server? (both box1 and box2 are runnning linux).

Comment: Regarding the telnet connection issue, few, if any, public-facing server have insecure telnet servers running.

Comment: Yes, I realize that now, and should've withdrawn my question after I called my ISP. They told me port 25 is blocked. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

See comments. Looks like my sendmail configuration and dns setup is ok. ISP is blocking port 25. This is why telnet works in local network but not through internet.